# C++ Win32 Owner Drawn Button's Down State

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I had this working in my previous program that got lost when my hard drive crashed.

I vaguely remember how I did it, but haven't been able to find any solutions on google or msdn.

```
case WM_DRAWITEM: {

  // pointer to items draw structure and the id
  LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
  int ctlResID = pDIS->CtlID;

 if (ctlResID == IDC_TEST) {
     // button drawn here to pDIS->hDC // this works fine
     // now I want to draw the button differently if it is in its down state (holding the button down or w/e)
 }
```

Is what I have, I think I remember one of the values in the draw item struct tells, but I cant find anything about it online.

Does anyone happen to know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try checking [`ODS_SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775802(v=vs.85).aspx).